# Using Java classes(whole module with Spring/Hibernate dependency) in Grails

Tags: java, grails, jar

I have a Java/Spring/Hibernate application with a payment module. Payment module has some domain classes for payment subscription and transactions etc. Corresponding hibernate mapping files are there. This module uses applicationContext.xml for some of the configuration it needs.

Also, This module has a PaymentService which uses a paymentDAO to do all database related work.

Now, I want to use this module as it is(without any or minimal re-writing) in my other application(Grails application). I want to bring in the payment module as a jar or copy the source files to src/java folder in Grails.

With that background, I have following queries:

1. Will the existing applicationContext.xml for Spring configuration in the module will work as it is in Grails? Does it merge with rest of Grails's Spring config?
2. Where do I put the applicationContext.xml? classpath? src/java should work?
3. Can I bundle the applicationContext.xml in Jar(If I use jar option) and can overwrite in Grails if anything needs to be changed? Multiple bean definition problems in that case?
4. PaymentService recognized as regular service? Will it be auto-injected in controllers and/or other services?
5. Will PaymentDAO use the datasource configuration of Grails?
6. Where do I put the hbm files of this module?
7. Can I bundle the hbm files in Jar(If I use jar option) and can overwrite in Grails if anything needs to be changed? Which hbms are picked? or, there will be problems with that?

Too many questions! :)

All these concerns are actually before trying. I am going to try this in next few days(busy currently). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you'll want to consider:

- You'll need to package your applicationContext.xml to avoid namespace clashes - that is, you'll probably put it in src/resources/com/company/module/applicationContext.xml
- This application context really needs to be compatible with the grails application - it'll need to access the DB connection used by your app - make sure it doesn't define its own - See section 14 of the docs - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html
- Section 15 of the docs - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html describes using hibernate mapping files
- 15.4 points out some good articles - http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2006/06/20/hoisting-grails-to-your-legacy-db/ and http://www.infoq.com/articles/grails-ejb-tutorial

Probably not the exact answer you were looking for, but I hope this helps.